# Get HTML pape after Javascript loaded with webtest

Tags: pyramid, webtest

So I run Pyramid application and have a `.pug` template with embedded JS which will run after page loaded.

```
extends base.pug

block subcontent
    .container
        h1 Homepage

block scripts
    script.
        window.onload = function() {
            //- Load some JS and build page
        }
```

Here is the test code with `webtest`, so is there any way that I can get `resp.html` after the code in `window.onload` ran. Does `webtest` support or do I have to use another library?

```
class TestHomeView:
    def test_home(self, view):
        resp = view.testapp.get('/', expect_errors=True, xhr=True)

        # Validate content
        assert 'd3-chart line-chart' in resp.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Webtest can not execute JavaScript - you'd need a full browser implementation inside your Python testing library, which is not really feasible.

I think for testing client-side JavaScript you need a separate suite of tests - there are a bunch of competing JS libraries for testing, such as Jest or Mocha. This would get you started: https://2021.stateofjs.com/en-US/libraries/testing/